How to Enumerate Threads using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and Python ctypes?
This seems like it should print the thread ID of the first thread in the snapshot, but it always prints 0. What is wrong with it?
The following assumes that process ID 1234 is a real, running process.
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

pid = 1234

TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD = 0x00000004

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

class THREADENTRY32(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwSize',             wintypes.DWORD),
        ('cntUsage',           wintypes.DWORD),
        ('th32ThreadID',       wintypes.DWORD),
        ('th32OwnerProcessID', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('tpBasePri',          wintypes.LONG),
        ('tpDeltaPri',         wintypes.LONG),
        ('dwFlags',            wintypes.DWORD)
    ]

CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = (wintypes.DWORD, wintypes.DWORD, )
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = wintypes.HANDLE

h_snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, pid)

LPTHREADENTRY32 = ctypes.POINTER(THREADENTRY32)
Thread32First = kernel32.Thread32First
Thread32First.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE, LPTHREADENTRY32, )
Thread32First.restype = wintypes.BOOL
thread_entry = THREADENTRY32()
thread_entry.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(THREADENTRY32)

if kernel32.Thread32First(h_snapshot, ctypes.byref(thread_entry)):
    print(thread_entry.th32ThreadID)


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-thread-list

Listing:

[MS.Learn]: CreateToolhelp32Snapshot function (tlhelp32.h) which states (emphasis is mine):

[in] th32ProcessID
The process identifier of the process to be included in the snapshot. This parameter can be zero to indicate the current process. This parameter is used when the TH32CS_SNAPHEAPLIST, TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, or TH32CS_SNAPALL value is specified. Otherwise, it is ignored and all processes are included in the snapshot.


[MS.Learn]: Traversing the thread list (mentioned by @Luke in comments). All that has to be done is converting that to Python

[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) which contains a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions)


The problem is you only iterated the 1st thread which belongs to (dummy) System Idle Process (which has the (dummy) PId 0, and a bunch of threads with (dummy) TId 0).
Here's an example.
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys
from ctypes import wintypes as wts


TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD = 0x00000004
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wts.HANDLE(-1)
ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES = 0x12


class THREADENTRY32(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("dwSize", wts.DWORD),
        ("cntUsage", wts.DWORD),
        ("th32ThreadID", wts.DWORD),
        ("th32OwnerProcessID", wts.DWORD),
        ("tpBasePri", wts.LONG),
        ("tpDeltaPri", wts.LONG),
        ("dwFlags", wts.DWORD)
    )

LPTHREADENTRY32 = cts.POINTER(THREADENTRY32)


kernel32 = cts.windll.kernel32

CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.argtypes = (wts.DWORD, wts.DWORD)
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot.restype = wts.HANDLE

Thread32First = kernel32.Thread32First
Thread32First.argtypes = (wts.HANDLE, LPTHREADENTRY32)
Thread32First.restype = wts.BOOL

Thread32Next = kernel32.Thread32Next
Thread32Next.argtypes = (wts.HANDLE, LPTHREADENTRY32)
Thread32Next.restype = wts.BOOL

CloseHandle = kernel32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.argtypes = (wts.HANDLE,)
CloseHandle.restype = wts.BOOL

GetLastError = kernel32.GetLastError
GetLastError.argtypes = ()
GetLastError.restype = wts.DWORD


def main(*argv):
    pid = int(argv[0]) if argv and argv[0].isdecimal() else None
    print(f"Searching threads for PId: {'ANY' if pid is None else pid}")
    flags = TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD
    snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(flags, 0)
    if snap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        print(f"CreateToolhelp32Snapshot failed: {GetLastError()}")
        return -1
    #print(snap)
    entry = THREADENTRY32()
    size = cts.sizeof(THREADENTRY32)
    entry.dwSize = size
    res = Thread32First(snap, cts.byref(entry))
    idx = 0
    while res:
        if pid is None:
            print(f"  TId: {entry.th32ThreadID} (PId: {entry.th32OwnerProcessID})")
        else:
            if entry.th32OwnerProcessID == pid:
                print(f"  TId: {entry.th32ThreadID}")
        idx += 1
        res = Thread32Next(snap, cts.byref(entry))
    print(f"Enumerated {idx} threads")
    gle = GetLastError()
    if gle != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES:
        print(f"Error: {gle}")
    CloseHandle(snap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output:

[cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q078690213]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py 30516
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32

Searching threads for PId: 30516
  TId: 9480
  TId: 28000
Enumerated 4831 threads

Done.


